# Hypothesis Testing and Z-test for happiness at work

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, sample-size, population, z-test

I'm doing a school project and decided to look closer into this COVID-19 thing that is obviously going on at the moment. I have a hypothesis that people in teams (at work) are happier at work after the COVID-19/Work-From-Home (WFH) situation. I've made a questionnaire with a set of Likert-scale statements in the form of "I Totally Agree" - "I Totally Disagree", with a "*Neutral*" field in the middle of the continuum. Now my data gathering period is over and I'm ready for the analysis, but before I'm proceeding I wanted to hear from you guys.

To test this hypothesis I'm planning to use a single sample Z-test, where the null hypothesis is that there is no effect on happiness at work after COVID-19/WFH (mean value would be at the *neutral* point) and the alternative hypothesis is that people are happier than before COVID-19 (mean value greater than the *neutral* point).

**Q1**: Is Z-test a valid statistical hypothesis test in this case?

**Q2**: Is it safe to assume a normal distribution (which is a requirement in Z-tests) in this case?

**Q3**: I got a total of 533 respondents (sample size n=533), but the population is unknown. Does that have any consequence?

**Q4**: Is it OK to use the neutral point in the Likert scale as the mean for the null hypothesis?

I also plan to use Python and the statsmodels.stats.weightstats.ztest for the testing, assuming Z-test is the way to go.

Appreciate all feedback and the effort from all of you competent people.

Thanks, and stay safe!

(edited typos)

T

Comment: Exactly what Likert scale do you have? I doubt it's a 'continuum', 5-point or 7-point? // Likert data are categorical, not numerical; thus I think it may be stretching too far to assume normal numerical data. // If the reported scores are approximately symmetrical, then it may be OK to use a one-sample Wilcoxon signed-rank test. // In Q3 you seem to be saying the subj were-self selected; you need to take that into acct in your conclusions and disclose it clearly in your report. (It may be that people who hate being back in the workplace choose not to participate, esp, if answering from work.)

Comment: You cannot validly draw any of the conclusions you would like.  At best, you might be able to conclude that people *report* that they *remember* being less happy before the pandemic.  Also, you articulated only half the alternative hypothesis: you also have to include the possibility people remember being more happy before the pandemic.  Finally, it sounds like "got 533 respondents" is not a random sample.  Thus, no statistical test that assumes randomness (like a Z test) will be valid.